# Crash After updating Parse Framework 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, xcode6

It's been a while since i've update my Parse Framework.
I've deleted parse from my project folder and then copy the new updated parse framework.
I've added the missing libraries since the last update (libzSQL3). 
after cleaning my app, i've tried to run it and getting this error:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[BFTask           taskFromExecutor:withBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x33c140'
 *** First throw call stack:
```

I went to the docs and there's nothing new over there, can anyone point me how to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you need to update your Facebook SDK.  Go directly to developer.facebook.com, download the SDK and copy over the FacebookSDK and the Bolts framework.  You should be set after that.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone coming across this, delete the Facebook SDK, and just add parse and bolt. 
apparently bolt (bolt the SDK that come with parse) and Facebook SDK can't live side by side ( maybe an update will help but I don't need Facebook sdk since parse got all what I need) thank you!